# Understanding numpy zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I have a piece of code in a file I was going through `np.zeros(X[-1].shape[0]))`. Here I understand `numpy` is assigning 0 but what does the `shape[0]` does here

Comment: Please, specify the value of `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem `X` is likely a list or array such that taking `X[-1]` returns the last element which must then be an array or slice of one. Then the shape of that array or slice is taken and the length of the first dimension is returned. For example if you had a list of arrays:

```
>>> X = [ np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), np.array([10,11]) ]
>>> X[-1]
np.array([10., 11.])
>>> X[-1].shape
(2,)
>>> X[-1].shape[0]
2
>>> np.zeros(X[1].shape[0])
array([ 0.,  0.])
```

If instead `X` were simply a numpy array then the last element would be a slice:

```
>>> X = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> X[-1]
array([[18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26]])
>>> X[-1].shape
(3, 3)
>>> X[1].shape[0]
3
>>> np.zeros(X[1].shape[0])
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 2):

`shape` is a tuple with a length equal to the number of dimensions of an array. So if you have:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 3)
```

`shape[0]` will refer to the first dimension.

Answer (score 0):

When you can't understand an expression, it helps to break it down:

```
np.zeros(X[-1].shape[0]))
```

This is calling `np.zeros` on something:

```
X[-1].shape[0]
```

… which is accessing the first element, `[0]`, of something:

```
X[-1].shape
```

… which is accessing the `shape` attribute of:

```
X[-1]
```

Now, assuming X is a multidimensional array `X[-1]` is the last row of that array. Which is another array.

So `X[-1].shape` is the [`shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) attribute of arrays: a sequence of the dimensions.

So, if `X` were a 3x3x3 array, then `X[-1]` would be a 3x3 array, so `X[-1].shape` would be `(3, 3)`.

And `X[-1].shape[0]` is just the first dimension: `3`.

So, we're creating a 1D array of zeros whose size is that of the first dimension of a row of `X`.

Answer (score -1):

The `shape` variable is a tuple that looks like `(cols, rows)`. That means that `shape[0]` refers to the number of columns of `X[-1]`.